# In Go, is there any way to compare two mixed-type interfaces without nested switch statements?

Tags: go, interface, type-switch

Go's `interface{}` type is both the best and most annoying feature of the language, I find. I'm trying to create a simple user-customisable validation rule solution where the user can define:

- The comparison operator.
- The comparison operand.
- The map key that leads to the value to test.

As well as a simple Boolean expression parser that allows the user to combine multiple rules using AND and OR. So far it all works well, the expressions can be parsed, tokenised, and evaluated successfully, but it's running the rules on the given data that causes problems.

This is the current version of the function that actually evaluates the data:

```
/*
validate returns a boolean value denoting whether a test was successful. This
function will panic if the type assertions fail.
*/
func (sfvre standardFieldValidationRuleEntry) validate(fieldValue interface{}) bool {

    switch sfvre.Operator() {
    case VROP_EQUAL:
        return fieldValue == sfvre.ComparisonOperand()
    case VROP_NEQUAL:
        return fieldValue != sfvre.ComparisonOperand()
    case VROP_GT:
        return fieldValue.(int) > sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(int)
    case VROP_LT:
        return fieldValue.(int) < sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(int)
    case VROP_GTET:
        return fieldValue.(int) >= sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(int)
    case VROP_LTET:
        return fieldValue.(int) <= sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(int)
    case VROP_CONTAINS:
        return strings.Contains(fieldValue.(string), sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(string))
    case VROP_NCONTAINS:
        return !strings.Contains(fieldValue.(string), sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(string))
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

At the moment the operator implies whether the data is numeric (greater than, less than, etc.). The type assertion to int did the job while building the other parts of the package, but the finished system should also be able to take float64 and be able to handle mixed type comparisons.

The only way I can see of doing this at the moment is by having multiple nested type switches, a level for each of:

- The operator.
- The type of the field value given.
- The type of the comparison operand.

But this has the potential to become very large and not easily manageable. Is there a 'cleaner' way to do this that I can't see, or am I stuck using nested switches?

Comment: How could a cleaner way work? Consider a comparison between `int64` and `uint64`. Such a comparison **must** handle a lot of cases, e.g. uint64-values unrepresentable by int64 and vice versa. Such cases are depending on *both* types, comparing uint32 to complex128 has different rules. If you have n types and m operators you will have to handle `n * (n-1) * m/2` cases (if I did the math right). And there is no shortcut. Or you limit any input to something representable by float64 and convert anything to float64 first (maybe handling strings separately).

Comment: I was hoping someone more knowledgeable with Go would be able to reveal it to me :( I'll probably end up converting everything to float64.

Comment: How about you just cast every number that comes in as a float? Int -> float loses precision in a way that isn't suitable for comparison so your mixed type comparison is going to be int to float, may as well just convert/cast everything to float64 prior to any comparison logic.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal see my answer :) before any comparison takes place (assuming it's numeric) I've put the interface values into concrete types. I'm afraid there's gaps in my knowledge about floating point but I was under the impression you would only get rounding errors/inaccuracies when you tried to add a large float to a small float (so always order your terms before adding)?

Comment: @leylandski floats will have small errors in precision but that doesn't begin til like idk 10-20 decimal places out. I was just trying to make the point that if you give me an int and a float and want to compare them, there is no real decision to be made, they need to be compared as floats. If you really demand precision you won't be using floats anywhere in the first place, equality comparison is not reliable on the type due to the precision errors you alluded to. Applications that need extremely precise decimal numbers typical use complex types that represent the decimal values with ints.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've got as of now (thanks to @Volker for the suggestion) does a quick type switch on the values that need comparing and then instead of using the originals in the `Operator()` switch, it uses the concrete float values:

```
/*
validate returns a boolean value denoting whether a test was successful. This
function will panic if the type assertions fail.
*/
func (sfvre standardFieldValidationRuleEntry) validate(fieldValue interface{}) bool {

    var floatFieldVal, floatCompVal float64

    //If the interface is int or float, convert it to a statically typed float64.
    switch fieldValue.(type) {
    case int:
        floatFieldVal = float64(fieldValue.(int))
    case float64:
        floatFieldVal = fieldValue.(float64)
    }

    //Do the same with the comparison value.
    switch sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(type) {
    case int:
        floatCompVal = float64(sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(int))
    case float64:
        floatCompVal = sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(float64)
    }

    switch sfvre.Operator() {
    case VROP_EQUAL:
        return fieldValue == sfvre.ComparisonOperand()
    case VROP_NEQUAL:
        return fieldValue != sfvre.ComparisonOperand()
    case VROP_GT:
        return floatFieldVal > floatCompVal
    case VROP_LT:
        return floatFieldVal < floatCompVal
    case VROP_GTET:
        return floatFieldVal >= floatCompVal
    case VROP_LTET:
        return floatFieldVal <= floatCompVal
    case VROP_CONTAINS:
        return strings.Contains(fieldValue.(string), sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(string))
    case VROP_NCONTAINS:
        return !strings.Contains(fieldValue.(string), sfvre.ComparisonOperand().(string))
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

It doesn't catch everything, but restricting what operators the user can choose based on what field they're comparing can mitigate this, but that's part of the larger solution so irrelevant here.